# AWK - reading columns from two files

Tags: awk

). Need your assistance. I have two shell script which produces output as below

script 1 output (abc.txt) -->

```
application_name      Status
abc                   Available
def                   NotAvailable
xyz                   Available
```

script 2 output (def.txt)-->

```
application_name      Status
abc                   NotAvailable
def                   Available
xyz                   Available
```

As you can see the application name in both the files are in same sequence but the status is different i.e. e.g. in one file the status for application abc is available and in other it is not available. I have to write a awk script to output a third file with the final status for each application. e.g. If the status for application abc in file abc.txt is "available" and in file def.txt it is NotAvailable, then the status of the application should come as as "NotAvailable"..Please find below the sample output file -

Final_output file (xyx.txt)

```
application_name     status
abc                  NotAvailable
def                  NotAvailable
xyz                  Available (since the status of this application is "available" in both the input file).
```

I tried to do it with the below command but it is not working. It is giving wrong output

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f1[$1]=$0; next} $1 in f1 && $0 != f1[$1] || $0 == f1[$1]' abc.txt def.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In summary, an application is `Available` only if it is available in both files.  In that case:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {if ($2=="NotAvailable")f1[$1]=$0; next} $1 in f1 {print f1[$1];next} 1' abc.txt def.txt
application_name      Status
abc                   NotAvailable
def                   NotAvailable
xyz                   Available
```

#### How it works

To summarize the rules:

1. If an application is NotAvailable in the first file, then its final status is NotAvailable regardless of what is in the second file.
2. If an application is available in the first file, then its final status is whatever the status is in the second file.

The following code implements those rules:

- `NR==FNR {if ($2=="NotAvailable")f1[$1]=$0; next}`

  When going through the first file, save the status of all NotAvailable applications.
- `$1 in f1 {print f1[$1];next}`

  If an application was NotAvailable in the first file, print its status from the first file  (NotAvailable).
- `1`

  Otherwise, print the status from the second file.  (`1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print the current line.)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{s[$1]=$0;next} $2=="Available"{$0=s[$1]} 1' file1 file2
application_name      Status
abc                   NotAvailable
def                   NotAvailable
xyz                   Available
```

Answer (score 0):

previous answers are fine and I will not add my two cents concerning `awk`. But in order to stand on the Unix philosophy, you may be intreested by the `join` tool. It will be pre-installed on any Linux distribution; just type:

```
join f1.txt f2.txt
```

end see what happens; you will then easely pipe the output to your own `awk` or `sed` command after that (and tune the behaviour of join after having had a look at `man join`).

Best regards.

Comment: I actually said my answer wasn't a full answer but rather a hint. I agree (and again, I said it) more post-processing has to be done. But the original poster may be interested by this command which is very close to his/her needs; if the file spacing isn't a major requirement, an elegant solution could be built by piping two short and easy to read commands.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment but you are mistaken in this specific case. Join is not close to the OPs needs and using join (or cat or paste or anything else as a first phase to combine the input files) would not allow you to create a solution that is briefer, more elegant, or better in any other way than using a single command that simply operates on the 2 original files. Of course, it's possible there's something I just haven't thought of so if you'd care to edit your question to show what you had in mind...?

Comment: Thanks all for all your help...i got the answer..i will have to learn the AWK tricks a little bit more :-)